# rails3 + jquery - behave differently on ajax request depending on source of request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

my app has a bunch of organizations. Each organization allows a user to join/leave the organization. If the last person leaves an organization, the organization is automatically destroyed.

I want to handle the join/leave requests via ajax. Joining/leaving can happen from two places: the index view which lists all the organizations and the show view which describes a particular organization.

The issue is that I want the logic in my leave.js.erb file to be different depending on where the leave button is being clicked. If the leave request is coming from the show view (and assuming this destroys the organization), then I want the user to be redirected to the index view. If the leave request is coming from the index view (and assuming this destroys the organization), I want to simply remove the html for the network in the index view.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this? I can think of roundabout ways by passing an extra parameter to the leave request which contains the "source" and using this "source" in my controller logic/leave.js.erb file. Not sure if that is the best way. Also, if that is the recommended way, how do I get the "source" when rendering the leave button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you'd better check the origin of the request using:

```
request.referer
```

in your controller.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea since a significant number of browsers don't send the referer.

Comment: @Peder: could you please tell which?

Comment: E.g.: "Some users may not wish to share that information with websites while they browse due to privacy concerns. This Chrome extension blocks the transmission of the referrer header to sites, by adding rel=noreferrer to every link on web pages." https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkpkjedlegmelkogpgamcaemgbanohip

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way IMO would be to have two actions, index_leave and show_leave, since the flow is different. The two actions should call a model method called leave_organization on the User model so that the code remains DRY.

I think you have tried to have only one action instead of two because you are thinking about the API to the web server as a data store API rather than an application controller API. If you want to use your web server as a data store then you need to implement the controller logic on the client side (i.e. you shouldn't rely on the leave.js.erb file for controller logic).